# Redirecting seo friendly urls to subdomains mapped to domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect seo friendly urls to a subdomain mapped to my main domain so the subdomains don't really contain anything. It's only cosmetic.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)-([0-9]+).html /videos/r/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^watch/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).html$ /videos/$2-$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/\.]+)-([0-9]+).html$ watch.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)/([^/\.]+)-([0-9]+).html$ watch.php?id=$3 [L]
```

this produces domain.com/video/seofriendyurl.html and i want it to redirect to subdomain.domain.com/video/seofriendlyurl.html. It's only cosmetic. So if I go to domain.com/video/seofriendyurl.html I want to be redirected to subdomain.domain.com/video/seofriendlyurl.html instead.

Answer (score 1):

when using `[R=301]` it's advisable to use an FQDN.
From the [apache2 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

> Prefix Substitution with http://thishost[:thisport]/ (which makes the new URL a URI) to force a external redirection.

so your RewriteRules would be

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)-([0-9]+).html http://subdomain.domain.com/videos/r/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^watch/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).html$ http://subdomain.domain.com/videos/$2-$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/\.]+)-([0-9]+).html$ watch.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)/([^/\.]+)-([0-9]+).html$ watch.php?id=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Nothing as in no change, or nothing as in no page is displayed?

Comment: In that case, your `RewriteRule` isn't catching the URL you're inputting. Without more clear test cases such as actual URLs which should match the rules you have it'd be impossible for us to help. I would also suggest testing your `RewriteRule`s in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.